# What is this feathery reddish/white "weed" that has popped up in a meadow area?

Tags: identification, weeds, meadow

This is another one I've never seen. A meadow mix was seeded in 2 years ago, so it might even be something desirable rather than a weed.

[image]

Comment: The plants are dying: you see the fruits. Maybe if you look better, you may see a living plant (with flowers), which could help on identification. A think it is a Brassicaceae. It is difficult to go further.

Comment: I agree it's a brassica species. Perfectly normal to find that in a wild meadow. You are looking at the seed pods. Most likely some species of rapeseed, mustard or something similar, not something that looked like a "cabbage" while it was growing.